# Typescript: force compile error when deconstruction tuple and missing an element

Tags: typescript

See this code:

```
function get(): [string, string] {
    return ['foo', 'bar'];
}

[foo] = get();      // -> error

[foo, bar] = get(); // -> ok
```

I want to get a compile time error when I miss the second argument. The reason is that I want to return errors this way and I want to make sure I never forget to handle them.

Is this possible? I could not find a solution but I might be searching incorrectly.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is a good way of handling errors in Typescript. Go has this baked into the language itself and can check for when you don't "handle" the error (even though it's not really error handling) but you don't have that option in typescript with tuple destructuring. Is there a specific reason why you're avoiding throwing errors?

Comment: @Xetera yes Go is the source of my inspiration. :) The problem is I don't get compile time errors for not catching thrown errors. Also, I find that being forced to do something with the returned error makes me write more robust code. So you too believe it is not currently possible what I want. Thanks for your input!

Comment: What would be the benefit of forcing you to declare the extra variable `bar` which, presumably, would be an unused variable anyway? The point of destructuring assignments like these are that you're extracting the parts of the data that you need, which is consistent with ignoring parts that you don't need. If you do need all of the data then just don't destructure it.

Comment: @kaya3 I do want to use it - or declare that I'm intentionally not using it. The benefit is not missing it _by accident_. If I don't deconstruct it, I can still forget about it.

Comment: If you do want to use the value, but you miss it out of the destructuring assignment, then the variable will be missing from your code, so you'll get an error for using an undeclared variable, no?

Comment: @kaya3 not exactly. Imagine the `get()` function first only returns `foo` so I neither expect `bar` nor use it. All is good. Then I later introduce the second return value `bar` (or `err`) and update most places but maybe miss a few.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that isn't possible and honestly doesn't have much to do with static type checking as destructuring return parameters is part of ECMAScript, it is simply a language feature. You cannot currently add any such constraints using TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Too bad. As for what belongs to static type checking and what does not, I disagree, it is a compiler choice. _Static type checking_ simply means checks done on the source, not at run time.

Comment: static type checking means that the types are checked, what you are looking for goes beyond typing, as you want to find out, if all return values of an array were processed by your app, which has nothing todo with the types. Perhaps linters can help you and there is a rule for what you are trying to achieve in eslint or tslint